# Labelling of a multidimensional array obtained from images

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

I have 6 ndarray in numpy format with shape in the form (80, 50, 170, 110) float64

Sample input

data
https://github.com/ichatnun/spatio-spectral-resnet-bottlenecks-rice-classification/blob/master/x.npy

label
https://github.com/ichatnun/spatio-spectral-resnet-bottlenecks-rice-classification/blob/master/labels.npy

total of 600 images belongs to 6 different classes.

I wanted to assign a multi-class label to all of them like 0,1,2,3,4,5. I have a created a separate numpy 1d array for the labels of each numpy dataset,

now I wanted to merge the label to the dataset so that I can join all the ndarray to make my data all together in the shape of (600, 50, 170, 110) with labels.

I have tried the concatenate, append, hstack method but it gives the error.

Error message

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Expected output

Assign a label and create a single ndarray of the dataset.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your inputs and a sample of your desired output? The dimensions you describe aren't totally clear

Comment: Hello, I have updated the input.